# Indexing but not ranking in search

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I’ve run into an SEO issue and I’m just completely stumped.  I currently am working on a website. This is the 3rd round of SEO work being done and I just can’t comprehend why we our pages aren’t being ranked. I thought maybe the community and/or experts could give me a few insights on what I could do. We've been on Google since 2015 so we don't really count as a new site

We are being indexed according to google console but we CANNOT find our pages on a normal user search 
Eg) Searching “Search keyword” (I've removed the keyword as forums request it not to be too site specific)

Will not return a result with our page. However when searching site specific “site:sitename Search keyword”

We can find the page.

Things we have tried

- Add unique metadescription , metakeywords for each course, institute
- Making each page only have 1 unique H1 (we have a few H1’s around the page)
- Decrypt the URLs so they are more user friendly 
  FROM: https://domain/CourseDetail/Index?q=zMux4giccufMsCJ3aHvcC1DsXg/lqPtKxR5z+UbeqEOdutH+nxvteuiEVYftZ3/T
  TO:
  https://domain/Index?courseID=28954&instituteID=90&course=national-certificate-in-diversional-therapy
- GZIP’ed the whole site with IIS
- Resubmitting sitemap with new content
- Back links
- Social Media Accounts

I've looked at other Stack Exchange threads, but most of the solutions posed doesn't work for us. I understand that there's a wait element in it but we've worked on this 3rd round SEO for 2 months and we just cant seem to get it
Here's some statistics from the search console that might provide some insights
[image: Google Search Console Statistics]

Any help provided would be much appreciated

Comment: Sorry but nothing jumps out at me as being an obvious issue. Questions to ask are do you have a lot of backlinks and are they truly high quality? [details](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google). I don't think there is a clear cut answer for you here, unfortunately. You might need to hire an SEO expert to give you a proper diagnosis.

Comment: Here's one thing: Your website loads in 7.6s from my browser in the USA, and 8.6s from webpagetest.com in Sydney, Australia. You might be getting hit with a site slowness penalty by Google.